# What softwares do you need inorder to develop a firmware application with Atmel 89C2051 micro-controller?

Tags: c, assembly, microcontroller, firmware, 8051

Please list some software/s and links which can help me build firmware for Atmel 89C2051 micro-controller. Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Atmel AT89C2051](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card.asp?part_id=1938) is a 20 pin version of the popular 8051 microcontroller.   The program memory (Flash) is limited to 2K and all the instructions related to jumping or branching should be restricted such that the destination address falls within the physical program memory space of the device.  The [Atmel AT89C2051](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card.asp?part_id=1938) also has all of the normal 128 bytes of RAM as well as the built-in UART.

The [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc0368.pdf) (PDF link) is often a good place to start when developing firmware for a microcontroller.

---

Since the [Atmel AT89C2051](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card.asp?part_id=1938) is fully compatible with the [MCS-51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51) architecture, and can be programmed using the [MCS-51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51#Instruction_set) instruction set, http://www.8052.com should be a good resource.

http://www.google.com/search?q=89C2051+site:www.8052.com

---

The open source [Small Device C Compiler (SDCC)](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/) toolchain can be used to produce the necessary firmware files for programming the Atmel chip.

The [Atmel C51ASM](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=5008) assembler is a two-pass macro assembler for the Atmel AT89 Family of 8051 microcontrollers and, according to the documentation, supports the AT89C2051.

---

The Stack Overflow questions [tagged 8051](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/8051) may also be of use.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Keil µVision](http://www.keil.com/c51/) for developing firmware for microcontrollers with MCS51 instruction set. It was convenient, but it was not free and trial version had some limitations on size of firmware.

Comment: If I remember correctly Keil imposes a 2K limit with the [evaluation versions](http://www.keil.com/c51/devproc.asp) of their tools.

Comment: @jschmier: presumably that should work nicely with the 89C2051's 2K of flash :-)

Comment: @psmears: it appears the Keil C51 evaluation tools impose several [limitations](http://www.keil.com/demo/limits.asp) including some that may be a problem for single-chip devices that support 2K or less of program space

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 or 3 things:

1. Develop the firmware: Depending on what programming language you are good at, you may use assembly language [**a51** & **asem51** are good assemblers], c cross-compiler [**keil c51** free trial version should be sufficient] or even basic [you can find a basic compiler for 8051 on the net].
2. The firmware should be in Intel hex format; if your assembler/compiler output is binary code, you need a `bin2hex` utility to convert the binary code to hex format. You can find freeware `bin2hex` utilities on the web.
3. A programmer [this is hardware] for loading the firmware into the microcontroller's program memory.